# How to send data which get from the input form then send them to my email address without open a new window? I am currently using angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

This is the data what I want to send to my email address. How can I implement a method to achieve this?

```
 {Name: "John", phoneNumber: "12364597"}
    Name: "John"
    phoneNumber: "12364597"
    __proto__: Object



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

 submit(f) {
   console.log(f.value);
 

}

  constructor() { }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use mailto

```
submit(f) {
window.location.href = `mailto:mail@example.org?subject=look at this website&body=Hello Iam ${f.value.name} and here is my phone no. ${f.value.phoneNumber}`;
}
```

Or else send mail from backend or use external package

Comment: Hi, am i type right in this way, 
mailto:jqyszq@gmail.com?subject=look at this website&body=Hello Iam ${f.value.name}
 and here is my phone nu. ${f.value.phoneNumber}

I didn't get that data when I check my email.

Comment: what you wrote is right, call that function which has the step i have written, it will open a email with data appended in it.